# How to make detail view in django html?

Tags: python, html, django

How can I show the data based on its id ?

now, if I click one item, i got the url like this
    http://localhost:8000/novel/11

for now, this is the views.py i've write

```
 def novel_page(request, id):
     return render(request, 'novel.html')
```

and the urls.py is

```
 path('novel/<int:id>', views.novel_page, name='novel'),
```

and I want to show the detail of item with id like what I passed to url.

For example, if I click the data with id is 11, so the system will display all of data based on id 11.

The data is'n from database, but from the XML file with the preview like this:

```
<Collection>
    <DOC>
        <DOCNO>1</DOCNO>
        <Title>Neon Prey (A Prey Novel) Hardcover </Title>
        <Author>John Sandford</Author>
        <Text>
            This is novel 1
        </Text>
    </DOC>
    <DOC>
        <DOCNO>2</DOCNO>
        <Title>The Mother-in-Law</Title>
        <Author>Sally Hepworth</Author>
        <Text>
            This is novel 2
        </Text>
    </DOC>
    <DOC>
        <DOCNO>3</DOCNO>
        <Title>Saman</Title>
        <Author>Ayu Utami</Author>
        <Text>
            This is novel 3
        </Text>
    </DOC>
</Collection>
```

This is the views.py to pass the data to the index

```
def display(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text = request.POST['input_text']
        result = main.main(text)
        content = {'result': result}
        return render(request, 'index.html', content)
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

and i show the data with this code

```
{% for i in result %}
    <h4><a href="/novel/{{i.docno}}">{{i.title}}</a></h4>      
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why an XML file?

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="{% url 'novel' id=i.docno %}">{{i.title}}</a>
```

You should always use url to build the link unless it's very special occasion that you have to render the path yourself. In such case, you should write a custom template tag to do so.

Comment: Hello Wils, i think i dont have problem with the url. The system has been successfully pass the id to the url, but i dont know how to display another data like title, author, and other data based on that id

Answer (score 1):

Your detail function should query the database to bring a particular data in ID 11 so for that you just need a django query . So your fuction will be like:

`views.py`

```
def novel_page(request, id):

     qs = YourModelName.objects.get(id=id)           # <------This is what you add

     return render(request, 'novel.html', {'qs': qs})       #<---- Pass the qs as a dict
```

Comment: Hello sir, actually i dont use database, the data that i use is data from data with format xml with tag : docno, title, author, and others, so the docno will be the id for this document.

Comment: From the index, the system only show the title of the data. When i click the title, the system will go to another page with the url that will be continue with the id of the data

Comment: I get it, can you post a single instance of  xml and how are you getting data on index (views code for that).